# LibGDX Sounds Issue

Tags: android, libgdx, game-physics, audio

I am developing a game for Android and the Desktop with LibGDX.  I am having a problem with playing sounds.  The game is a labyrinth style game, there are balls that roll around on the device using the accelerometer.  When balls hit the border, or one another a sound is played.  The volume is set based on the linear velocity of the collision.  The problem is, when the balls get really close to the border, they bounce many times in a small period of time.  This ends up bogging down the main thread, and the UI starts to stutter.  In log-cat it says "reducing sample rate" or something like that, because it can't handle the load.  Also, when there are a bunch of collisions, the sounds keep playing after there aren't anymore collisions.

I need each of the sounds to be played independently of the other sounds.  I was thinking, maybe creating a separate thread for the sounds.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I working now with the sounds of my game. The last LibGDX version works fine playing a lot of sounds simultaneously. All you need to do is, if you plan to play them on the same time is control the number of maximum sounds played (more sounds requires more resources of the device) and reduce the sample rate and quality of the most played. You can resample your sound with Audacity. Try to save it as a OGG file with less quality and try again. Also, you can create your sound as static and play it many times from the same sound without create a new one.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you! This are some good advices. I will try to control the number of maximum sounds. Do I just need to change the variable? Or are there other needs like updating via a method?